# Replace add to cart button based on weight in WooCommerce single products

Tags: php, wordpress, button, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I've searched for replacing add to cart button conditionally on woocommerce. I got a code and I've modified it as per my need. Its working perfectly on the shop page.

Here is My code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replace_default_button', 10, 2 );
function replace_default_button( $button, $product ){
    global $product;
    $weight = $product->get_weight();
    preg_replace('/\D/', '', $weight);
    if ( $product->has_weight() && ($weight > '8') ){
        $button = '<a href="#" class="button alt">' . __( "Add to Quote", "woocommerce" ) . '</a>';
    }
    return $button;
}
```

But I need a similar code for single product pages as well.
How should I do that? Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can simplify your code a bit like:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replace_default_button', 10, 2 );
function replace_default_button( $button, $product ){

    $weight = $product->get_weight();
    preg_replace('/\D/', '', $weight);

    if ( $weight > 8 ){
        $button = '<a href="#" class="button alt">' . __( "Add to Quote", "woocommerce" ) . '</a>';
    }
    return $button;
}
```

Then to have something similar for single products pages use the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'action_single_product_summary_callback', 1 );
function action_single_product_summary_callback() {
    global $product;

    $weight = $product->get_weight();
    preg_replace('/\D/', '', $weight);

    if ( $weight > 8 ) {

        // For variable product types
        if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'add_to_quote_replacement_button', 20 );
        }
        // For all other product types
        else {
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'add_to_quote_replacement_button', 30 );
        }
    }
}

function add_to_quote_replacement_button(){
    echo '<a href="#" class="button alt">' . __( "Add to Quote", "woocommerce" ) . '</a>';
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.